Why is NumPy's vectorized evaluation slower when storing vectors as class attributes?
I am writing a helper class to evaluate a parametrized function over a grid. Since the grid does not change with the parameter, I chose to create it once and for all as a class attribute.
However, I realized having the grid as a class attribute causes a significant performance drop as compared to having it as a global variable. Even more intriguing, the performance discrepancy noted for a 2D grid seems to disappear with a 1D one.
Here is a minimum "working" example demonstrating the issue:
import numpy as np
import time


grid_1d_size = 25000000
grid_2d_size = 5000
x_min, x_max = 0, np.pi / 2
y_min, y_max = -np.pi / 4, np.pi / 4

# Grid evaluation (2D) with grid as class attribute

class GridEvaluation2DWithAttribute:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x_2d_values = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, grid_2d_size, dtype=np.float128)
        self.y_2d_values = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, grid_2d_size, dtype=np.float128)

    def grid_evaluate(self):
        cost_values = np.cos(self.x_2d_values[:, None] * self.y_2d_values[None, :])
        return cost_values

grid_eval_2d_attribute = GridEvaluation2DWithAttribute()
initial_time = time.process_time()
grid_eval_2d_attribute.grid_evaluate()
final_time = time.process_time()
print(f"2d grid, with grid as class attribute: {final_time - initial_time} seconds")

# Grid evaluation (1D) with grid as global variable

x_2d_values = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, grid_2d_size)
y_2d_values = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, grid_2d_size)

class GridEvaluation2DWithGlobal:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def grid_evaluate(self):
        cost_values = np.cos(x_2d_values[:, None] * y_2d_values[None, :])
        return cost_values

grid_eval_2d_global = GridEvaluation2DWithGlobal()
initial_time = time.process_time()
grid_eval_2d_global.grid_evaluate()
final_time = time.process_time()
print(f"2d grid, with grid as global variable: {final_time - initial_time} seconds")

# Grid evaluation (1D) with grid as class attribute

class GridEvaluation1DWithAttribute:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x_1d_values = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, grid_1d_size, dtype=np.float128)

    def grid_evaluate(self):
        cost_values = np.cos(self.x_1d_values)
        return cost_values

grid_eval_1d_attribute = GridEvaluation1DWithAttribute()
initial_time = time.process_time()
grid_eval_1d_attribute.grid_evaluate()
final_time = time.process_time()
print(f"1d grid, with grid as class attribute: {final_time - initial_time} seconds")

# Grid evaluation (1D) with grid as global variable

x_1d_values = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, grid_1d_size, dtype=np.float128)

class GridEvaluation1DWithGlobal:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def grid_evaluate(self):
        cost_values = np.cos(x_1d_values)
        return cost_values

grid_eval_1d_global = GridEvaluation1DWithGlobal()
initial_time = time.process_time()
grid_eval_1d_global.grid_evaluate()
final_time = time.process_time()
print(f"1d grid, with grid as global variable: {final_time - initial_time} seconds")

And this is the output I get:
2d grid, with grid as class attribute: 0.8012442529999999 seconds
2d grid, with grid as global variable: 0.20206781899999982 seconds
1d grid, with grid as class attribute: 2.0631387639999996 seconds
1d grid, with grid as global variable: 2.136266148 seconds

How to explain this performance discrepancy?
I moved the grid from a class attribute to a global variable. I expected this change to be neutral to performance. However, a significant change of performance resulted.

By the way, keep in mind that the type float128 doesn't actually have 128 bits of precision. You may be losing performance vs float64 for a fairly small gain in precision.

You aren't consistent with setting the datatype of your grid.
Compare
self.x_2d_values = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, grid_2d_size, dtype=np.float128)
self.y_2d_values = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, grid_2d_size, dtype=np.float128)

With:
x_2d_values = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, grid_2d_size)
y_2d_values = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, grid_2d_size)


When not specified, the default type is np.float64, which is 2 times shorter and at least two times faster than np.float128, which matches the time you've measured.

the default type depends on your platform. Usually on *Nix, it is float64, on windows it can be float32

actually, I think the above only applies to int types, float types default to float64 on all platforms from what I'm reading
